Hall effect sensor RPM detection via breadboard circuit
I have been using the AH1815 Hall effect sensor with an Arduino and a breadboard circuit to determine RPM value of a magnetic tribune. The RPM value was detected by reading unit steps on an oscilloscope. The circuit has some problems while detecting.
Are there other instruments that can handle the task? I was also wondering about measuring data using breadboard circuits and taking data via Bluetooth adapter. The other sensors I was looking for were DRV5013-Q1 sensor and AD22151 sensor.

What was your issue with the Arduino? It might be the easiest solution for you to use an Arduino. It's easy to work with, it is powerful enough and can return the value you want in the serial console.
But if you want to measure the number of pulses in a given time, or the time between two pulses, you need to familiarize yourself with timers. There a plenty of tutorial online on how to measure pulse timings.

I agree with blup, an arduino or other MCU circuit is your best bet. It's not always plug and play though. You may need hardware or software filtering, or complex timer configurations to get stable results at high speeds.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Much more data on problems and circuit would help. What is a magnetic tribune? What is it doing? What RPM range? || Long ago I designed RPM sensor for use in a very electrically noisy environment. I'd HOPE your task was not too hard. Knowing what problems you are having in detail will help us to help you.
